# Function that returns fields not equal to something

Tags: python

Hello so I have this function:

```
#Checks and strips out empty
def filterWithAccum(fields):
    if fields == u'':
        accum.add(1)
    return fields != u''
```

What I want to do is add more possibilities like != u'NULL' but I don't think you can do a return with a or clause in it. What is the recommended approach?

Comment: I don't know exactly what your function is supposed to be doing, but a `return` statement can in fact have an `or` in it. For instance, `return True or False` is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: What's the idea of `accum`? it isn't even defined inside the function

Comment: accum is a spark accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can return the result of an expression. If you want to add further tests simply write them, using logical connectors. For instance:

```
return fields != '' and fields != 'NULL'
```

Comment: I think what he wants to happen is, "return all elements of `fields` such that each element is not equal to '' or 'NULL'"

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking "how can I return a sequence of items that are in some sequence `a` but not in some other sequence `b`?" Then you can use the `in` operator in conjunction with a list comprehension:

```
def filter_out_nullish_things(a):
    b = [u'', u'NULL']
    return [item for item in a if item not in b]
```

Comment: So what is weird is: [u'NULL', u'18949', u'18960', u'18958', u''] it will filter the u'' but will not filter the u'NULL'